# Kotlin type reference in when case

Tags: kotlin

Consider the below snippet

```
   when(value){
        Int-> FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCustomKey(key, value as Int)
        Long-> FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCustomKey(key, value as Long)
        Float-> FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCustomKey(key, value as Float)
        Double-> FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCustomKey(key, value as Double)
        else -> FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCustomKey(key, value.toString())
    }
```

I would like to somehow reference the type in the when case, so I can do something like that

```
   when(value){
        Int, Long, Float, Double -> FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCustomKey(key, value as type)
        else -> FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCustomKey(key, value.toString())
    }
```

Is it possible in Kotlin? Please submit a feature request if not ;p

Comment: I believe this is not possible, because `setCustomKey()` for specific types has to be resolved at compile time. `Int` and `Long` branches compile to a different bytecode, they reference totally different methods (only named the same). It is impossible to handle different types with the same bytecode and therefore we probably need a separate source code as well.

Comment: 1. For type pattern mathing you need to use `is` keyword (`is Int`, `is Long`, etc.)
2. No need for explicit cast of `value` inside branches - Kotlin will do smartcast for you.
3. Required syntax is absent in Kotlin

Answer (score 1):

You can get runtime type of `value` and the relevant method overload with reflection:

```
val crashlytics =  FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance()
when (value) {
    is Int, is Long, is Float, is Double -> crashlytics::class.declaredMemberFunctions
        .single { it.name == "setCustomKey" && it.parameters[2].type.jvmErasure == value::class }
        .call(crashlytics, key, value)
    else -> crashlytics.setCustomKey(key, value.toString())
}
```

It will have only 2 branches, but also a certain performance penalty (and relaxed type safety), so I'd suggest to stick to original approach:

```kotlin
when(value) {
    is Int-> FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCustomKey(key, value)
    is Long-> FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCustomKey(key, value)
    is Float-> FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCustomKey(key, value)
    is Double-> FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCustomKey(key, value)
    else -> FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCustomKey(key, value.toString())
}
```